# issue on interfacing adt7410 with yocto

Tags: sensors, i2c, yocto, device-tree

I am trying to interface an I2C device ADT7410 with yocto but i am getting this error

adt7410: probe of 4-0048 failed with error -5

and my device tree modification is

```
TempSen: adt7410@48 {
    compatible = "adt7410","adt7x10";
    reg = <0x48>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-1 = <&pinctrl_edt_ft5x06_pins>;
    interrupt-parent = <&gpio3>;
    interrupts = <1 2>;
};
```

please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Your problem is related to device-tree modification and in general communication with temperature sensor rather than with yocto itself. Please consider adding some details about your hardware configuration, kernel version etc.

Comment: We are using smarc-samx6i distributed by kontron they are using processor of Freescale imx6q.                                                           Image Name:   Linux-3.10.17-rel1.0+g232293e

Comment: and also can you tell me how we can give "interrupt-parent = <&>;" This parameter value ?